# How do I create a Cognito Identity with Facebook token

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I have followed through all the steps in the documentation, user pool for registration through an email/pwd combo (working), configured FB identity provider in both the identity pool and user pool section for identity providers, and implemented the following code example found here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/facebook.html and modified below using my identity pool.

{code}

```
function facebookLogin(){
    FB.login(function (response) {

        // Check if the user logged in successfully.
        if (response.authResponse) {

        console.log('You are now logged in.' + response.authResponse.accessToken);

        // Add the Facebook access token to the Cognito credentials login map.
        AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
            IdentityPoolId: 'us-east-1:eb997110-50b3-4e40-97ff-fbaf796da9ef',
            Logins: {
                'graph.facebook.com': response.authResponse.accessToken // cognitouser.idToken
            }
        });
        console.log('Added FB access token to Cognito.');

        // Obtain AWS credentials
        AWS.config.credentials.get(function(){
            //getCurrentUser();
            console.log('Got the aws creds.');
        });

        } else {
        console.log('There was a problem logging you in.');
        }
    });
}
```

{code}

I can step through and see the FB token being passed into CognitoIdentityCredentials and there are no errors but a user never gets registered in either my Identity Pool or User Pool.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I am having the same issue at the moment. Anyone has A solution? Thanks.

Comment: I never did get it and ended up doing a custom solution for FB and Google.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of the code I use for creating Federated Identities in AWS

```
    function loadCredentials(identityPool, provider, accessToken) {

        var params = {
            /*AccountId: window.appInfo.accountId,*/
            //RoleArn: window.ap
            IdentityPoolId: identityPool,
            Logins: {}
        };
        params.Logins[provider] = accessToken;
        AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials(params);
        AWS.config.credentials.get(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err.message);
                console.log(err.stack);
            }
            else 
            {
                console.log("Cognito Identity Id: " + AWS.config.credentials.identityId);
                console.log("Worked");
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: This is the same code posted as example, how is this helping to get users registered in cognito using fb?